# Is it possible to supply render settings for jOOQ code generation?

Tags: h2, jooq

I'm trying to run the jOOQ code generator against an H2 database, but am encountering the following exception:

```
23:59:27.191 [main] ERROR org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase - Could not load schemata  
org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured
        at org.jooq_3.11.7.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:319)
        ...
```

I have verified that the database does in fact exist. I suspect this is due to a mismatch in case-sensitivity handling:

- jOOQ quotes names for all schema objects as a means of specifying case-insenstivitiy... however,
- H2 uses quotes to enforce case-sensitivity.

I'm aware of how to specify render settings programmatically to use generated artifacts (building queries and such), but in this particular case I'm looking for a way to specify those settings in configuration for the code generator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The artificial stack trace element `at org.jooq_3.11.7.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)` indicates that you're using the [`SQLDialect.MYSQL`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#MYSQL) dialect to generate your SQL code, which obviously doesn't work on H2. Also, your `Configuration` doesn't have a JDBC connection as the error message indicates, so you cannot actually execute any queries through jOOQ.

The code generator doesn't offer the functionality you're looking for. In order to "unquote" all identifiers, use the [identifier style settings at runtime](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/).

Comment: hi Lukas - I'm not using the `MySQL` dialect but rather connecting to H2 using in/with MySQL compatibility mode. But I achieved my desired goal programmatically using the `GenerationTool` -> withGenerator -> withStrategy -> withMatchers -> withSchemas -> withSchemaClass -> withExpression -> AS_IS.